# WebDav Displayname property missing

Tags: c#, webdav

I have a problem with [this](https://github.com/saguiitay/WebDAVClient) WebDavClient library for C#. I use the following code to establish a connection to a SVN repository:

```
using (var webdavClient = new WebDavClient())
{
    var result = await webdavClient.Propfind(uri);
    if (result.IsSuccessful)
    {
      ....
    }
 }
```

After debugging through the C#-library, the actual request seems to work fine. However, there is no *displayname* property delivered, and I have no idea why the *displayname* property is missing in the response from the server. The response I get from the server looks like this:

```xml
<lp1:response xmlns:V="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/" xmlns:S="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/svn/" xmlns:C="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/custom/" xmlns:lp1="DAV:" xmlns:lp2="http://subversion.tigris.org/xmlns/dav/">
  <lp1:href>/svn/repo/folder1</lp1:href>
  <lp1:propstat>
    <lp1:prop>
      <lp1:resourcetype>
        <lp1:collection />
      </lp1:resourcetype>
      <lp1:getcontenttype>text/html; charset=UTF-8</lp1:getcontenttype>
      <lp1:getetag>W/"2//folder1"</lp1:getetag>
      <lp1:creationdate>2016-11-11T12:11:28.864862Z</lp1:creationdate>
      <lp1:getlastmodified>Fri, 11 Nov 2016 12:11:28 GMT</lp1:getlastmodified>
      <lp1:checked-in>
        <lp1:href>/svn/repo/!svn/ver/2/folder1</lp1:href>
      </lp1:checked-in>
      <lp1:version-controlled-configuration>
        <lp1:href>/svn/repo/!svn/vcc/default</lp1:href>
      </lp1:version-controlled-configuration>
      <lp1:version-name>2</lp1:version-name>
      <lp1:auto-version>DAV:checkout-checkin</lp1:auto-version>
      <lp2:baseline-relative-path>folder1</lp2:baseline-relative-path>
      <lp2:repository-uuid>54432e45-83a1-49ac-b790-da67dd1d131f</lp2:repository-uuid>
      <lp2:deadprop-count>0</lp2:deadprop-count>
      <lp1:lockdiscovery />
    </lp1:prop>
    <lp1:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</lp1:status>
  </lp1:propstat>
</lp1:response>
```

A few months back, WebDav-Library was working as expected, but now, however, I can't get it to work anymore. Do you have any suggestions where to look at or what might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The DAV:displayname property is fully optional. Why would SVN return it, if it's going to match the last part of the path name anyway?

Comment: Okay, lets say I want to also return the DAV:displayname property from my SVN. How can I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a late turn, but it caught my eye and I wanted to write. TYPE: PROPFIND

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns" xmlns:nc="http://nextcloud.org/ns">
  <d:prop>
    <d:displayname />
  </d:prop>
</d:propfind>
```